# Laravel - how to make lists function concatenate first_name and last_name as one parameter

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a query for all the admins which I am sending to my view to a select box. I wonder how can I concatenate first_name and last_name as one parameter, so that I have the full name as my select options?

This is the query:

```
$admins = Role::where('name', 'admin')
                        ->first()->users()->get()
                        ->lists('first_name', 'id')
                        ->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `User` model you can define a method called:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute(): string
{
    return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}
```

Having this method you can use the `$model->full_name` attribute.

```
$admins = Role::where('name', 'admin')
                        ->first()->users()->get()
                        ->lists('full_name', 'id')
                        ->toArray();
```

Comment: @Marco for future refrence, this is called a mutator. See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator).